# US visa for transfer passenger

Tags: visas, usa, transit

A friend of mine is going to fly from Beijing to Toronto, but he'll stop over in Chicago for 7 hours. Does he need the US visa?

Comment: What is his citizenship?  In general, everybody who lands in the US, even for transit, no matter how short, needs a visa unless they are eligible for a visa waiver or other visa-free entry.

Answer (score 0):

The US requires that all passengers arriving at a US airport, whether for transit purposes or not, have permission to enter the US. This means that passengers must be one of:

- US citizen or permanent resident (green card holder)
- Canadian citizen (or one of some other small visa-free exceptions)
- Citizen of a VWP (Visa Waiver Program) country, with ESTA
- Holder of a US visa

Comment: Permanent residents do not need a visa, just a green card.

Comment: Oh right, I knew I'd miss something! Thanks.